# Flutter/Dart Uri not escaping colon ":" in URL

Tags: http, url, dart, flutter, uri

The following uri created:

```
final _url = "https://example.com/api/";
final _uri = Uri(path: _url, queryParameters: _params);
```

Results in `http%3A//example.com/api/+{params...}`

I have tried escaping by `\:` and other methods but no luck :/

This problem only happens when run through Uri, I was unable to find any resources online to resolve this issue.

Comment: Use `Uri.http` or `Uri.https` https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/Uri/Uri.http.html https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/Uri/Uri.https.html

Comment: Just to ask, why didn’t you flag my answer as the correct one?

Comment: I wanted to give both of them ticks, but it wouldn't let me sorry :/ thanks for your help!

Comment: I believe this is a bug in the uri constructor code. The docs say "The percent-encoding of the path segments encodes all characters except for the unreserved characters and the following list of characters: !$&'()*+,;=:@.". Since ":" is in the list, I would expect it not to be encoded. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri/Uri.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So the best way to create an URI in Dart from a url string is using the [`Uri`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/Uri-class.html) dart package with its static methods [`http`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/Uri/Uri.http.html) or [`https`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/Uri/Uri.https.html)

So you have to change your code as the following:

```
final _authority = "example.com";
final _path = "/api";
final _params = { "q" : "dart" };
final _uri =  Uri.https(_authority, _path, _params);
```

[image]

Comment: what about if you have example.com/api/company/query and example.com/api/asset/query or example.com/api/asset  , route changes after api in my case

Answer (score 11):

Your intention is

```
final String _url = "https://example.com/api/";
final Uri _uri = Uri
    .parse(_url)  // parse string
    .replace(queryParameters: _params);  // set params (no need manual escape, Uri do it itself)
```

Comment: smart way. If no params then just `Uri _uri = Uri.parse(_urlString)`

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for

Answer (score 8):

Replace:

```
final _url = "https://example.com/api/";
final _uri = Uri(path: _url, queryParameters: _params);
```

with:

```
final _url = "example.com/api/";
final _uri = Uri.https(path: _url, queryParameters: _params);
```